# How to remove unwanted visual elements from selenium element screenshot

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webpage-screenshot

I am trying to scrape the commodities futures table (https://www.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures)

scraping itself goes well (i.e. getting the table html code and so on), but I want to get the screenshot of this table. And everytime i try i am getting unwanted artifacts like popup windows, [breaking news pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2W3V.png), [duplicate navbars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY22O.png), [ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URweN.png).

Is there a way to remove them from viewspace of the table?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, FirefoxOptions
from Screenshot import Screenshot_Clipping

ss = Screenshot_Clipping.Screenshot()

url='https://www.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures'

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = True
with webdriver.Firefox(options=options) as browser:
    browser.maximize_window()

    browser.get(url)

    element = browser.find_element_by_id("cross_rate_1")
    
    img_url=ss.get_element(browser, element, r'.')
```